# React Native - If else null not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I wrote an if else `null` see below and it works fine.

```
{this.state.tomorrow.length > 0 ?
    <ListItem itemDivider style={{backgroundColor: 'crimson'}}>
        <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Tomorrow</Text>
    </ListItem> : null
}
```

Then I wrote this on another page and its not working, what am I doing wrong?

```
 <Grid>                                  
     <Row style={{paddingBottom:10}}>
         <Col>
             <Text>Location:</Text>
         </Col>
         <Col>
             <Text>{ this.state.appointment.location }</Text>
         </Col>
     </Row>
     {this.state.appointment.location_bool ? <Text>Hello</Text> : null }
 </Grid>
```

Error I get is:

> Cannot read property 'type' of null

Thanks

Comment: 2nd part is working without this line: `{this.state.appointment.location_bool ? <Text>Hello</Text> : null }` ?? i think issue is somewhere else, r u using type at any place ?

Comment: @MayankShukla Yeah it works fine without that line - not using type anywhere.

Comment: r u fetching the `appointment` data from server by any api call ?

Comment: @MayankShukla Yes

Comment: try one more thing, put that line inside Row in Col ?

Comment: @MayankShukla Do you think, putting taht line in row will solve the issue?

Comment: not sure but may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <Grid>                                  
     <Row style={{paddingBottom:10}}>
         <Col>
             <Text>Location:</Text>
         </Col>
         <Col>
             <Text>{ this.state.appointment.location }</Text>
         </Col>
     </Row>
      <Row>
          {
             this.state.appointment.location_bool ?  
                 <Col> <Text> Hello </Text>  </Col> 
                 : 
                 null
          }
      </Row>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: Great. Happy to help.

Comment: Any explanation as to why this works, given that it looks syntactically incorrect given the missing closing curly brace surrounding the ternary operator...